# How to load newest data into UITableView First - Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

So for a school project i have to make a swear jar, everything is finished but i need to know how to display the newest swears at the top of the UITableView instead of the bottom.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which your `dataSource` is ordered it's up to you, when you set your `dataSource` you can order by any property you have in your `class/struct`, etc and it's the order in which it will be presented to the user. When you use the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to populate your `UITableView` it assume the order of your `dataSource`, like in the following code:

```
var array = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // here is populated your tableview in the same order of your dataSource is specified if you want it.

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
   cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]

   return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return array.count
}
```

You should see a `UITableView` with `Item 1` in the firs row, `Item 2` in the second and `Item 3` in the third.

I hope this help you.

Comment: yes this helps, sorry i was brief in my desciption i was in class. Im loading the data from core data after saving the data in another view controller

Comment: It's no problem, just order your data your before pass it to your `UITableViewViewController` or `UIViewController` and it will help you.

Comment: i am trying to but its giving me "an error has occured - please retry your request" ill make sure i get it done tonight for you

Answer (score 0):

Just put the swearword at the beginning of the array.